# scrapy sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been getting sslv3 errors in scrapy after updating it.

```
2017-09-11 17:33:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-09-11 17:33:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-09-11 17:33:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6025
2017-09-11 17:33:20 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://api.citypantry.com/packages/search?page=1&sortBy=relevance> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]>]
```

Versions:

```
Scrapy    : 1.4.0
lxml      : 3.8.0.0
libxml2   : 2.9.3
cssselect : 1.0.1
parsel    : 1.2.0
w3lib     : 1.18.0
Twisted   : 17.5.0
Python    : 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) - [GCC 6.2.0 20160914]
pyOpenSSL : 17.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)
Platform  : Linux-4.8.0-59-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.10-yakkety
```

It works by using **requests** library.

Comment: Is python 3 an option?

Comment: I have tried it using python3 and python2 but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Please reinstall scrapy by running `pip install scrapy --force --upgrade`

Comment: Issue is confirmed with different version combinations, please open an issue on scrapy github repo